# How to "forget" user credentials after logging in to a windows share (samba)

Tags: login, password, samba

I logged in from my Mint to a windows share (which is actually a linux running samba, if it's relevant), typed in the password, and got it. Even though I marked it to forget the password immidiatly, it stills let me log in without retyping the password.

This is a problem since the username/password I'm using will determine which folder I will be shown.

How do I force Mint to forget the credentials?

Answer (score -1):

Rebooting your machine after marking can fix this

Comment: The idea is to do so without rebooting though

Comment: I agree.  That being said, sometimes rebooting sorts the issue. Its worth a try. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Yes, but I rebooted the system before posting the question. Again, that is completely not my question, I have a few directories I'm trying to access and they will be displayed based on the user I'm logging in as, rebooting the system so I can access 2 different directories is absord.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/572816)